# Akka Camel multiple consumers

Tags: apache-camel, akka, activemq-classic, akka-cluster, akka-camel

I'm using akka + camel to consume message from activemq, and I'm trying to figure out how to deploy this consumer in multiple machines without duplicate the message. In this case I'm consuming message from a topic and the activemq should know I have one akka system in various machines, instead of various single independent systems.

I tried to accomplish that using akka cluster, but that example using a frontend that subscribe to a cluster of backend does not help since my "backend" actor is the activemq consumer itself and I can't tell activemq to subscribe to my cluster.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMS versions < 2.0 does not allow multiple nodes to share a topic subscription (not duplicating the message to each consumer). To cope with that ActiveMQ provides Virtual Topic (you can consume messages published to a topic from a Queue which allows for multiple consumers - load balancing).

It's all naming conventions. So you simply publish to the topic `VirtualTopic.Orders` and then consume from the queue `Consumer.ClusterX.VirtualTopic.Orders`. Naming conventions could be changed - see docs.

http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html